# Multi-Data Type Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have data with text, categorical, and numeric columns and would like to find a clustering algorithm that can handle all three of these data types. [image]

I am struggling to find a solution that would enable me to use one distance metrics across all of these features or an algorithm that would enable me to use a custom distance metric (so I could create one of my own).

I am trying to implement this in python.

Answer (score 0):

### Transformation

So you have text, DateTime, categorical and numerical data.

- text data can be transformed into numerical data, using [sklearn.feature_extraction.text](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) module for instance ;
- datetime-string can be transformed using [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then using [dt.dayofweek](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html) ;
- categorical data can be [one-hot-encoded](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) ;
- numerical data stay like that or you can bin it.

## Distance metric

To deal with mixed-type distance issues, you can either :

- [normalize](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) the features after this and use an adapted metric (Manhattan may do the job) ;
- use a custom metric (without normalization required upstream). This second approach can be done using [sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html)
- use a clustering algorithm that deals with [mixed-type data natively](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.04364.pdf).

In unsupervised learning techniques, you are quite free to innovate in order to change the data space or the clustering principles as you don't have a performance metric that is king. (like RMSE in regression)